# Liveness probe failed when using lettuce instead of jedis in spring-starter-data-redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis, lettuce

I have a spring boot application using spring cloud bom : `Hoxton.SR1`
The app is deployed in a kubernetes cluster.

To connect the app to the redis database I tested 2 different configuration :

- Jedis connection pool configuration :

`pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- jedis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`application.yml` :

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    password: password
    database: 0
    jedis:
      pool:
        min-idle: 0
        max-idle: 12
        max-active: 12
        max-wait: 500ms
```

Deployment in the K8S cluster works well.

- Lettuce connection pool configuration :
  `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!--lettuce connection pool-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`application.yml` :

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    password: password
    database: 0
    lettuce:
      pool:
        min-idle: 0
        max-idle: 12
        max-active: 12
        max-wait: 500ms
```

Deployment in the K8S cluster DOES NOT WORK, error is : `Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.68.13.246:8080/actuator/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`.

What am I missing ?
What could be the root cause of this ?
Is it related to spring actuator or lettuce connector ?

Comment: Is there a sample project to reproduce the issue?

Comment: There is not for now, but I should have one soon with k3s instead of k8s. I hope I will be able to reproduce the exact same error.